# Revoke Oauth Authorization

Tags: oauth-2.0, autodesk-forge

As a user, how do I revoke authorization given to an app?
Or as an app, how do force a new authorization?

I did not see anything in the user page or in the API documentation regarding revoking:

https://accounts.autodesk.com/users/{{user}}/view
https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/reference/http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to revoke from the admin console at the moment unfortunately. As an App you may request different set of scopes which should trigger the user to authorise it again